# how to create single product pages from array of objects

Tags: javascript, next.js

I would like to know how it is possible to create a page for each object in array with unique url. I am using Next.js.

**Input Array**

```
const products = [
  {
    url: "item-1",
    id: 1,
    name: "Item 1",
    description: "lorem...",
    price: 10
  },
  {
    url: "item-2",
    id: 2,
    name: "Item 2",
    description: "lorem...",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    url: "item-3",
    id: 3,
    name: "Item 3",
    description: "lorem...",
    price: 30
  },
]
```

I would want to use `{"/products/" + product.url}` as page url and use other info to display product on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Under `pages` create a directory `products`
2. Inside `products` create a file called `[prod].tsx`

Inside the `[prod].tsx` file resolve the product code (here there is an example):

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ProdPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { prod } = router.query;
    return <div>Product: {prod}</div>;
};

export default ProdPage;
```

You can create urls like:

```
/products/abc
```

Please, have a look here: [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)